# Array converted implicitly to container class when passed as argument in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, instantiation, implicit

I was working on a project and, while playing around with the code, I came across the following peculiar occurrence.

I have two classes. The first holds three floats in an array representing Cartesian coordinates and defines a method to get those points;

```
class foo
{
protected:
    float m_Coordinates[3];

public:
    foo(float coordinates[3]);
    void GetPoints(int resultArray[]);
};

foo::foo(int coordinates[3])
{
    std::copy(coordinates, coordinates+3, m_Coordinates);
}

void foo::GetPoints(float resultArray[])
{
    std::copy(m_Coordinates, m_Coordinates+3, resultArray);
}
```

The second class also stores an array of floats, but its constructor uses foo as a wrapper class to pass the values:

```
class bar
{
protected:
    float m_MoreCoordinates[3];

public:
    bar(foo f);
};

bar::bar(foo f)
{
    f.GetPoints(m_MoreCoordinates);
    //m_MoreCoordinates is passed by reference, so the values in
    //m_MoreCoordinates are equal to the values in f.m_Coordinates
    //after this line executes
}
```

Please ignore the fact that the approach I've taken to this code is simply horrible. It started out as an experiment in using arrays. Passing them as arguments, getting them as return types etc.

OK. Here's where I noticed something strange. If I declare an array of floats and pass them as an argument to bar's constructor, the compiler will generate an instance of class foo and pass that to bar for me. See example code below:

```
int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    float coordinates[] = {1.0f, 2.1f, 3.0f};


    //Here the compiler creates an instance of class foo and passes 
    //coordinates as the argument to the constructor. It then passes 
    //the resulting class to bar's constructor.
    bar* b = new bar(coordinates);

    //Effectively, the compiler turns the previous line into
    //bar* b = new bar(foo(coordinates));

    return 0;
}
```

When I saw this, I thought it was a pretty neat feature of the code and was wondering how and why it happened. Is it safe to do this? I don't understand how it works, and so I don't want to depend on it. If someone could explain how this works, I'd really appreciate it.

**Edit:**
Thanks to Mankarse for pointing out how the conversion would be performed in the main. Initially, I had:

```
//Effectively, the compiler turns the previous line into
//bar* b = new bar(*(new foo(coordinates)));
```

Comment: The compiler actually turned the line into `bar* b = new bar(foo(coordinates));`.

Comment: @Mankarse is right, bar* b = new bar(*(new foo(coordinates))); would be leaked since the constructor passes by value. You would never have a chance to clean it up.

Comment: @Mankarse Ah, thanks for pointing that out. Java has simply ruined me. I never noticed that there'd be a memory leak there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, compiler is implicitly creating a `foo` object and passing it to `bar`. Generally, this is considered a bit dangerous as the `foo` gets constructed without knowledge, to avoid this you can declare `foo`s constructor as `explicit`. In that case compiler will not implicitly create `foo` from array of floats and you will get an compiler error.

Comment: Thanks very much. It was interesting behaviour on the part of the compiler. I've never seen it do that before. Thank you for explaining it.

Comment: People have argued that languages with unmanaged memory are unsafe. That doesn't mean they shouldn't be used and utilized as an invaluable language, just that you should know what you are doing before you use them.

Answer (score 1):

When you think about it, you use this all of the time. Consider the following:

```
void foo(std::string argument);
```

Then, suppose you invoke this function using a string literal:

```
foo("argument");
```

this is the same as:

```
std::string argument("argument");
foo(argument);
```

It's a pretty useful feature.

Comment: So we can always depend on the compiler to perform this conversion for us? You're right, that's a very useful feature. Although Naveen's suggestion that it be used with caution seems like good advice. Even from a readability perspective, relying on the compiler to create the class from the array of floats is not very clear coding. None the less, it is quite an interesting feature.

Comment: @GaryMunnelly I think it is plenty clear and readable that you can pass construction arguments for a type in a function definition. In fact, I think it usually makes the code more readable when used correctly. Anyways, to each their own.